# How do I move a label to a new line?

Tags: java, swt, label

Is there a new line command for SWT on windows? If there isn't, what am I doing wrong here?

Here's the code

```
    public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new TabsTest().createShell(display);
    shell.setSize(350,500);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
}

private Shell createShell(final Display display) {
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Betting Tracker");

    //Creating grid layout, used to organize the shell
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.numColumns = 20;
    shell.setLayout(gridLayout);

    //Grid1
    GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.CENTER, true, false);
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 20;

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("Bet Type:");
        betType = new Combo(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
        betType.setItems(new String[] {"   ", "NFL", "NBA", "CFB"});
        betType.setLayoutData(gridData);

    //Grid2
    GridData gridData2 = new GridData(GridData.BEGINNING, GridData.CENTER, true, false);
    gridData2.widthHint = 20;   
    gridData2.horizontalSpan = 5;

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("Bets Played:");
        numBets = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);
        numBets.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.CENTER, true, false));
        numBets.setLayoutData(gridData2);

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("    Won:  ");
        betsWon = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);
        betsWon.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.CENTER, true, false));
        betsWon.setLayoutData(gridData2);

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("    Lost:  ");
        betsWon = new Text(shell, SWT.FILL);
        betsWon.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.CENTER, true, true));
        betsWon.setLayoutData(gridData2);   

    //Grid3
    GridData gridData3 = new GridData(GridData.CENTER, GridData.CENTER, true, false);
    gridData3.horizontalSpan = 20;

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("Todays Lines");
        lines = new List(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        lines.setItems(new String[] { "OKC(+2.5) - MIA(-2.5)", "DAL(+8) - BOS(-8)" });
        int listHeight = lines.getItemHeight() * 12;
        trim = lines.computeTrim(0, 0, 0, listHeight);
        gridData3.heightHint = trim.height;
        lines.setLayoutData(gridData3);

    return shell;
}
```

}

The problem is where I create a new Label under the //Grid3 comment. That label is sticking to the line above it, rather than coming to a new line. I'm brand new at SWT so I know it's just lack of knowledge on my part. I'll include a picture so you can see the issue.

[image: picture]

You can see the label 'Todays Lines:' isn't on it's own line.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign more than once the layout data of the Texts, first to `new GridData()` then `gridData2`. Once is enough.
The reason the new label does not appear on the new line is that the grid has 20 columns as set with `gridLayout.numColumns = 20;`. `gridData2` has `horizontalSpan = 5`. If you add 3 labels (spanning 1 column as default) and three Texts spanning 5 columns (as per `gridData2`), the label you want on the new line will appear in the 19th column still on the same row.

I suggest to assign separate `GridData` instances to the Texts and divide the number of columns to span among them to sum up to 20 (e.g. the last one spans not 5 but 7 columns), this way 'Today lines' will be placed in the next row.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for tailoring it to my program specifically, makes it immensely helpful and more clear about what I am doing wrong. Thank you and merry Christmas!